# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with PowerShell and AWS

Tags: mysql, powershell, amazon-web-services

I have been searching the googles for the last two days to try and understand if I can do this.  I have a MySQL instace hosted on aws that I need to load a small CSV file to every hour.  The LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE seems to be the ticket, but I can't seem to find anywhere that shows me how to send it to an AWS MySQL instance with powershell from my machine.  Can someone help me with the code or at least point me to some examples?

I may be close, I finally found a video:

```bsh
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$csvPath = 'D:/ETL_Data/TwitchTVData.csv'
$srvr = "myRDS.rds.amazonaws.com"
$DB = "TwitchTV_Data"
$uid = "User"
$pwd = "PWD"
$conStr = @"
server=$($srvr);port=3306; database=$();uid=$($uid);pwd=$($pwd)
"@
$conObj = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection 
$conObj.ConnectionString = $conStr
$conObj.Open()
$queryStr = "LOAD DATA FROM $($csvPath)
    INTO TABLE TwitchTV_Top10_Game_Data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (Game_Name, Viewers, Channels, Snapshot);"
$cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($queryStr, $conn)
$conObj.Close()
```

I just get an authentication error.  so now I have to solve for that problem.

---

**Edit:**

I modified the original code to

```bsh
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$csvPath = 'D:\ETL_Data\TwitchTVData.csv'
$srvr = "myrds.rds.amazonaws.com"
$db = "TwitchTVData"
$uid = "user"
$pwd = "pwd"
$conStr = @"
server=$($srvr);port=3306; database=$($db);uid=$($uid);pwd=$($pwd)
"@
$conObj = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection 
$conObj.ConnectionString = $conStr
$conObj.Open()

$csv = Import-Csv $csvPath | select -First 3

foreach ($record in $csv) {
    $queryStr = "INSERT INTO TwitchTV_Top10_Game_Data ($columns) VALUES ('$($record.Game_Name)','$($record.Viewers)','$($record.Channels)','$($record.Snapshot)');"
    $cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($queryStr, $conObj)
}

$conObj.Close()
```

This executes, but doesn't do anything.  No data into the table, but no errors.

Following the answer below:

```bsh
$cred = Get-Credentials
$csvPath = 'D:\ETL_Data\TwitchTVData.csv'

$con = Connect-MySqlServer -Credential $cred -ComputerName myrds.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -Port 3306

#Define our column headings (needed for the Insert statement)
$columns = "Game_Name,Viewers,Channels,Snapshot"

#import our csv
$csv = Import-Csv $csvPath | select -First 3

foreach ($record in $csv) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO TwitchTV_Top10_Game_Data ($columns) VALUES ('$($record.Game_Name)','$($record.Viewers)','$($record.Channels)','$($record.Snapshot)');"

    "Executing : $query"
    Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query $query -Verbose
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```

This gives the error mentioned in the comments.

Comment: `LOCAL` may not work depending on if your client supports it.

Comment: Please show the error. Also, can you even connect to port 3306 on your VM (`telnet $srvr 3306`)?

Comment: yes I can connect; I finally managed to find another solution that works actually better than this any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I went WAYYY down a rabbit hole.

But I found an answer, however mine doesn't use PowerShell, but the `mysql` utility of `mysqldbimport`, you can download it [here](https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-utilities-1.6.5-winx64.msi). (Link to My Sql Utilities 1.6.5)

First thing first, you need to make sure you add a network rule to your database to allow it to patch the mySQL port, of `3306` to your VM.  Make sure your settings at least look like this:

[image]

Now, launch the `MySQL Utilities Console`, here's the command you'll want and the syntax.

`mysqldbimport --server=yourUserName:YourPassword@YourDBName.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 c:\PathTo\YourFile.csv`

If you need the endpoint name (What I called `YourDBName.us-east.etc` above, get it here.

[image]

I hope this helps!  I'll take a further stab and see if I can figure out the PowerShell syntax too.

## Doing it with PowerShell

Who am I to leave a friend hanging?  It's working in PowerShell too...with some caveats.  Here's how:

1. Download the [MySql ADO Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
2. Download Adam Betram's awesome MySQL PowerShell Module from [this blog post](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx)

So, to download and import Adam's module run the following:

```
invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://github.com/adbertram/MySQL/archive/master.zip -OutFile  'C:\temp\MySQL.zip'
expand-archive C:\temp\MySQL.zip c:\somepath\MySql
import-module c:\somepath\MySql\MySQL-master\MySQL.psm1
```

Now, to connect to your Amazon MySQL instance

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$con = Connect-MySqlServer -ComputerName yourDB-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -Credential $cred -Port 3306
```

Now, if you need to create a table, first define your column headings and data types in a hashtable like this.

```
$table = @{"DeviceType"="VARCHAR (10)"
"DriveLetter"="VARCHAR (10)"
"DriveType  "="VARCHAR (50)"
"FreeSpace"="VARCHAR (10)"
"LastLoggedonUser"="VARCHAR (10)"
"MachineName"="VARCHAR (10)"
"Manufacturer"="VARCHAR (10)"
"Model"="VARCHAR (10)"
"SpaceInMB"="VARCHAR (10)"
}
#run this command to create this table
 New-MySqlTable -Table newtable01 -Database test -Column $table -Debug
```

If it worked, you'll see the following

```
Tables_in_test
--------------
newtable02
```

I've got a .csv file just hanging out on my harddrive which has some info about computer hard drives, so I decided to import that, because it's Friday night and the kids are finally asleep and what else is dad gonna do for fun?

So when you're importing them, you're basically going to parse through each row and run an `INSERT INTO` command...but PowerShell is a huge pain in that it doesn't respect column order, so you'll have to list the column names...then the properties...in order.  It stinks.

Here's the rest of the code.  You'll modify to match your own column headings, of course.

```
#Define our column headings (needed for the Insert statement)
$columns="MachineName,Model,Manufacturer,LastLoggedonUser,DriveLetter,DriveType,DeviceType,SpaceInMB,FreeSpace"

#import our csv
$csv = import-csv C:\temp\input2.csv | select -First 3
 
 ForEach ($record in $csv){
    $query = "INSERT INTO newtable01 ($columns) VALUES ('$($record.MachineName)','$($record.Model)',`
             '$($record.Manufacturer)','$($record.'Last Logged on User')','$($record.DriveLetter)',`
             '$($record.DriveType)','$($record.DeviceType)','$($record.'SpaceInMB ')','$($record.'FreeSpace(NA)')');"

 "about to exec:$query"
 Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query $query -Verbose
 start-sleep -Milliseconds 250

}
```

Which in action looks like this

```
about to exec:INSERT INTO newtable01 (MachineName,Model,Manufacturer,LastLoggedonUser,DriveLetter,DriveType,DeviceType,SpaceInMB,FreeSpace) VALUES ('BLAHBLAH','Optiplex980',
             'Dell','DUDEBRO','C','WDCWD5000BEKT','Desktop','476837','NULL');
VERBOSE: 0 records found
about to exec:INSERT INTO newtable01 (MachineName,Model,Manufacturer,LastLoggedonUser,DriveLetter,DriveType,DeviceType,SpaceInMB,FreeSpace) VALUES ('BLAHBLAH','Optiplex980',
             'Dell','SOMEGUY','C','TOSHIBAMK2561GSYN','Desktop','238122','NULL');
VERBOSE: 0 records found
about to exec:INSERT INTO newtable01 (MachineName,Model,Manufacturer,LastLoggedonUser,DriveLetter,DriveType,DeviceType,SpaceInMB,FreeSpace) VALUES ('BLAHBLAH','Optiplex980',
             'Dell','HAMSANDWICH','C','ST9250410ASATADevice','Desktop','238','122');
VERBOSE: 0 records found
```

All that remains is to run `Invoke-MYSqlQuery -Query "Select * from newtable01 limit 5" | format-table` to see that it actually worked...

[image]

Comment: Wow, do you know how long I tried to find the actual download for that.  I can still make this work; I can simply add the command to a bat file and run it 2 minutes after my hourly CSV file update.  beautiful work.

Comment: Hey I figured out the PowerShell only commands!  Check back in a minute as I'm about to write it down.

Comment: Okay, that is nice work and an even better answer; the Get-Credential though would break my purpose of full automation so I have to figure out what the -Credential is expecting to see in terms of format.

Comment: I am also getting errors, the very first one is Cannot Validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName', but I am pretty sure that has to do with the credentials input.  I really have to figure out that format I think.

Comment: no matter what I do I get an error Connect-MySqlServer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The " Test-Connection -ComputerName $_
-Quiet -Count 1 " validation script for the argument with value "<myRDS>"
did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At D:\PS_Scripts\uploadtoMySQL.PS1:8 char:60
+ ... omputerName <myRDS>
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Connect-MySqlServer], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Connect-MySqlServer

Comment: Oh yah I forgot to mention that his module does not natively work well with Amazon. If you go to the modules psm1 file and search for test-connection, you'll see the line with that command. Just comment out that line in the module, reimport it and you'll be fine.

Comment: with all the headbanging over the last couple days I finally managed to get Talend ETL community edition to setup a job that takes me from end to end on this.  JSON -> XML -> XML Parse mapping table with variable that adds the date and then uploads it to my table.  You did great work here and I will continue to work on it to see if I can get it working after all.